# Visual Studio 2013 on SharePoint 2010 Farm

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, 2010, visual-studio-2013

Can Visual Studio 2013 be installed on a server which hosts SharePoint 2010? Are there any potential issues of installing it?

Comment: Well, one issue is that you can't create SharePoint 2010 solutions using VS 2013. You can open SP 2010 solutions, but not create such. EDIT: it seems the issue applied for a limited early versions of VS 2013 and likely isn't true as of today's versions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**As a short answer:** Yes you can install and create a `SharePoint 2010 Solution` using `Visual Studio 2013` without any issue.

[image]

**Note:** Don't forget to install `Office/SharePoint Template` tools to show `Office/SharePoint Template` for more details check [Couldn’t find Office/SharePoint template in Visual Studio Community 2013](https://blog.devoworx.net/2016/01/15/missing-officesharepoint-template-in-visual-studio-community-2013/)

Answer (score 2):

Visual Studio 2013 can be used to create SharePoint 2013 solutions. You can use VS 2012 for SharePoint 2010 solution. But you can open the solutions using VS 2013.

You ca find more info about VS 2013 here.

[Visual Studio 2013 Compatability Matrix.](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/hh266747(v=vs.120).aspx)

But there are few posts says it is possible with VS 2013 premium edition this we haven`t tried.

[Visual Studio Compatability for SharePoint 2010](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20431133/creating-a-sharepoint-2010-solution-in-visual-studio-2013)

Comment: While the Compatibility Matrix only mentions opening, [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22999040/3181315) answer suggests this isn't true.